# Spring Data JDBC - Kotlin support - Required property not found for class

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying to use Spring Data JDBC with Kotlin data-classes, and after adding `@Transient` property to primary constructor I received error on simple `findById` call:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required property transient not found for class mitasov.test_spring_data_with_kotlin.Entity!
```

my entity class looks like below:

```kotlin
data class Entity(
    @Id
    var id: String,
    var entityName: String,
    @Transient
    var transient: List<TransientEntity>? = mutableListOf(),
)
```

After reading [that issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/320) I've tried to make `@PersistenseConstructor` without `@Transient` field:

```kotlin
data class Entity(
    @Id
    var id: String,
    var entityName: String,
    @Transient
    var transient: List<TransientEntity>? = mutableListOf(),
) {
    @PersistenceConstructor
    constructor(
        id: String,
        entityName: String,
    ) : this(id, entityName, mutableListOf())
}
```

But this didn't help me and I'm still getting that error.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I personally recommend using Java instead of Kotlin's data class for JPA.

Comment: This is not JPA, this is JDBC, please be more attentive. Spring Data JDBC supports Kotlin nicely, see [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/2.1.2/reference/html/#mapping.kotlin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's turned out that my second attempt IS the solution.

The trick was in my Run/Debug configuration for tests.

In IDEA Preferences I have checked `Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner — Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven` checkbox, and this means that I need to manually recompile my project before running tests.

#### Solution

So, this is it, the solution for error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required property transient not found for class mitasov.test_spring_data_with_kotlin.Entity!
```

is making `@PersistenseConstructor` without `@Transient` fields:

```kotlin
data class Entity(
    @Id
    var id: String,
    var entityName: String,
    @Transient
    var transient: List<TransientEntity>? = mutableListOf(),
) {
    @PersistenceConstructor
    constructor(
        id: String,
        entityName: String,
    ) : this(id, entityName, mutableListOf())
}
```